# Best way to create server side of an app using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, client, socket.io

I am building an app for IOS and I want to use NodeJS on my server side. The server should handle requests with parameters to modify or get data from a mongodb database. I would like some advise  regarding the means to do this. Should I use Socket.io or express routing is good enough?

I started using express routing since this should be kind of restful. I build URLs with method and it's parameters on the client side and route and get parameters inside each handler method on the server side. It seems I can make authentication using Passport so this should not be a problem. What I find weird is how the request URLs get big with so many parameters...probably there's some trouble if a user sends a string with a slash in one of the parameters isn't there?

Almost forgot to mention (and please feel free to throw stones at me if this is too stupid): I was thinking about passing the parameters requests (in the case of routing) as a stringified JSON...is it as bad as it looks? For example:

- to get a user data: `url/users/findById/{"userid":"21312313"}`
- to add user: `url/users/addUser/{"name": "John", "lastname": "Foobar"}`

Should instead I use Socket.io?

Please advise.

Comment: socket.io is a great library, but it's really only meant for real-time push communication *in a web browser*. Support for socket.io on most other platforms is rather poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io is made for building real time nodejs application. if you are not mean to, then you can simply use expressjs web framework for simple restful api, which also serve the purpose.

> What I find weird is how the request URLs get big with so many parameters...probably there's some trouble if a user sends a string with a slash in one of the parameters isn't there?

as far as I understood above line, you can simply put your client parameters into `encodeURIComponent` method, which simply encode it in url format, so no worry. otherwise you can use **regex** expression at server side express routing.

> to get a user data: url/users/findById/{"userid":"21312313"}

you can simply accept the **userid** at server side using `req.body['userid']` if it is a post request else try with req.query...

Comment: +1 for passing JSON via POST rather than in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Socket.io is designed for different type of communication altogether. Simply put, it is good for having a communication layer established between the server and a client where the server can also initiate a message without a request.

You should look at RESTful API patterns. They define a good clean pattern to fetch, update, add and remove data using HTTP, following the proper standards. For example, getting a user's information would be sending a get request to `/users/id`, and adding a user would be doing a POST to `/users` with the user data as a JSON object in the post body.

Most of the articles I found about restful APIs weren't too good, but I think this should [suffice](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api).

Answer (score 1):

In restAPI there are some common practices.
For example:

Instead of

```
url/users/findById/{"userid":"21312313"}
```

use

```
GET url/users/findById/21312313
```

or

```
 GET url/users/findById?userid=21312313  
 //you will think of other as
 GET url/users/addUser?name=John&lastname=Foobar 
 //But it is wrong. While Adding things request should be handled by PUT or POST method not GET
 //when doing PUT or POST sent parameters are not included in url
```

see articles similar to http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api for more information